# Mysql count rows using filters on high traffic database

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, count

Let's say you have a search form, with multiple select fields, let's say a user selects from a dropdown an option, but before he submits the data I need to display the count of the rows in the database .

So let's say the site has at least 300k(300.000) visitors a day, and a user selects options from the form at least 40 times a visit, that would mean 12M ajax requests + 12M count queries on the database, which seems a bit too much .

The question is how can one implement a fast count (using php(Zend Framework) and MySQL) so that the additional 12M queries on the database won't affect the load of the site .

One solution would be to have a table that stores all combinations of select fields and their respective counts (when a product is added or deleted from the products table the table storing the count would be updated). Although this is not such a good idea when for 8 filters (select options) out of 43 there would be +8M rows inserted that need to be managed.

Any other thoughts on how to achieve this?

p.s. I don't need code examples but the idea itself that would work in this scenario.

Comment: the db that is being queried is it updated by the users? If not could you cache as much as possible to limit the db hit?

Comment: I friend solved a problem similar to this with use of memcacher. I haven't tried it yet so I cannot give you much more info. This is the website of memcached: http://memcached.org/

Comment: @sabre : yes it's updated by the users and by some automatic imports, there are atleast 5000 new products added each day

Comment: As alyo mentioned, cache the count with Memcache. You'll avoid hitting the db completely. Every time a new item is added to the db, increment the count you store in the cache.

Comment: @alyo : we allready use macached, however i don't think memcached will deal too well with the aditional 12M requests, caching results is a good ideea but when there are 5000 new products added, atleast 2000 edited by the users and 1000-2000 products deleted each day, from atleast 8 places in the site there would be a nightmare to expire the cache

Comment: The number of queries per day tells nothing. Are there peak times when the site runs noticeably slower?  Unacceptable slow?  Have you actually measured a performance problem?  If not, this might be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: @Michael J.V. : good point, however killing an mamcached instance will loose my data, so if the site needs to be moved to another cluster of servers it would be easyer if the data is not stored in memcached

Comment: By the way, did you mean "300,000" or "300k" instead of "300.000k"?

Comment: @Ferdindand Beyer : there is a countinous flow of optimisation on the db and site aswell, there arent' peek times when the site runs realy slow, but that's exactly what i'm trying to avoid when building this new feature, i can't go into production with a feature that might introduce slow responses on the peek times

Comment: yes i ment 300K ( 300.000 ), i'll edit the question

Comment: So recalculate the count if you move the site, it's not like world will end if you move the site and re-count the rows. In the end, you can create a count in the db itself. Create triggers after update / delete / insert operations and increment / decrement the count. If you move the site, look up the number in your db and cache it with Memcache.

Comment: I presume you're counting results? Why do you need an exact count? Estimating, like Google Search does, seems much more sensible.

Comment: @Nick Johnson : can't estimate couse on the listing you'll see the exact count, there shouldn't be any estimate between the form and the listing

Comment: @poelinca Why does the count have to be exact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a separate table that caches the counts, combined with triggers.

In order for it to be fast you make it a memory table and you update it using triggers on the inserts, deletes and updates.

**pseudo code:**

```
CREATE TABLE counts (
  id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key
  option integer indexed using hash key
  user_id integer indexed using hash key
  rowcount unsigned integer
  unique key user_option (user, option)
) engine = memory

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_tablex_each AFTER UPDATE ON tablex FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (old.option <> new.option) OR (old.user_id <> new.user_id) THEN BEGIN
    UPDATE counts c SET c.rowcount = c.rowcount - 1 
      WHERE c.user_id = old.user_id and c.option = old.option; 
    INSERT INTO counts rowcount, user_id, option  
      VALUES (1, new.user_id, new.option)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY SET c.rowcount = c.rowcount + 1; 
  END; END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Selection of the counts will be instant, and the updates in the trigger should not take very long either because you're using a memory table with hash indexes which have O(1) lookup time.

**Links:**
Memory engine: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html
Triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html

Comment: this seams like the way to go, do you know if i can have memory and disk storage tables under the same database ?

Comment: @poelinca, yes no problem you can mix all storage engines

Comment: thanks, sorry that the bounty would have expired and i had to give it away, i'll try to make it up some day

Comment: @poelinca, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

I would probably have an pre-calculated table - as you suggest yourself. Import is that you have an smart mechanism for 2 things:

1. Easily query which entries are affected by which change.
2. Have an unique lookup field for an entire form request.

The 8M entries wouldn't be very significant if you have solid keys, as you would only require an direct lookup.

I would go trough the trouble to write specific updates for this table on all places it is necessary. Even with the high amount of changes, this is still efficient. If correctly done you will know which rows you need to update or invalidate when inserting/updating/deleting the product.

**Sidenote**: 
Based on your comment. If you need to add code on eight places to cover all spots can be deleted - it might be a good time to refactor and centralize some code.

Answer (score 4):

there are few scenarios

1. mysql has the query cache, you dun have to bother the caching `IF the update of table is not that frequently`
2. `99%` user won't bother how many results that matched, `he/she just need the top few records`
3. use the `explain` - if you notice `explain` will return how many rows going to matched in the query, `is not 100% precise`, but should be good enough to act as rough row count

Comment: i need 100% acuracy and fast, without any seepd loses

Comment: @poelinca Then you want something for nothing, which just isn't possible. Any extra work you do is going to have some performance impact.

Comment: @Nick Johnson i know it will have a performance impact but it should be minimal , meaning i need to get the best solution out

Answer (score 3):

Not really what you asked for, but since you have a lot of options and want to count the items available based on the options you should take a look at Lucene and its faceted search. It was made to solve problems like this.

If you do not have the need to have up to date information from the search you can use a queue system to push updates and inserts to Lucene every now and then (so you don't have to bother Lucene with couple of thousand of updates and inserts every day).

Answer (score 3):

You really only have three options, and no amount of searching is likely to reveal a fourth:

1. Count the results manually. O(n) with the total number of the results at query-time.
2. Store and maintain counts for every combination of filters. O(1) to retrieve the count, but requires O(2^n) storage and O(2^n) time to update all the counts when records change.
3. Cache counts, only calculating them (per #1) when they're not found in the cache. O(1) when data is in the cache, O(n) otherwise.

It's for this reason that systems that have to scale beyond the trivial - that is, most of them - either cap the number of results they'll count (eg, items in your GMail inbox or unread in Google Reader), estimate the count based on statistics (eg, Google search result counts), or both.

I suppose it's possible you might actually require an exact count for your users, with no limitation, but it's hard to envisage a scenario where that might actually be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

A few things you can easily optimise:

1. Cache all you can allow yourself to cache. The options for your dropdowns, for example, do they need to be fetched by ajax calls? [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-memcached-faq.html) answered many of my questions when I implemented memcache, and of course memcached.org has great documentation available too.
2. Serve anything that can be served statically. Ie, options that don't change frequently could be stored in a flat file as array via cron every hour for example and included with script at runtime.
3. MySQL with default configuration settings is often sub-optimal for any serious application load and should be tweaked to fit the needs, of the task at hand.  Maybe look into [memory engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html) for high performance read-access.

You can have a look at [these 3 great-but-very-technical posts on materialized views](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/04/flexviews-part-3-improving-query-performance-using-materialized-views/),  as a matter of fact that whole blog is truly a goldmine of performance tips for mysql.

GOod-luck

Comment: In my opinion, there's no need for memory engine if you have sufficient amount of RAM and are using InnoDB engine. You risk losing the data and it's a nightmare to work with memory engine due to how quickly you can be out of your data.

Comment: I agree it is more trouble to work with but for applications that need high-speed high traffic read access to a limited data set, I was inclined to believe it was faster than InnoDB -> though to be fair I have absolutely no benchmark to back this up.  Only the fact that a former DBA we worked with in the past had converted a few highly solicited tables to memory engine, I have no idea of the speed gains these changes made as it is not a project I was assigned to. If all data is in ram it does make sense that InnoDB should be nearly as fast though. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You might be interested in HandlerSocket for MySQL / InnoDB, it basically allows for direct access over primary key to InnoDB stored records making InnoDB incredibly fast on machines with sufficient RAM (fast enough to outperform Memcache).

Comment: as stated we allready use memcached, and i don't think it would be a viable solution on it's own alone

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're using ajax to make the call to the back end that you're talking about. Use some kind of a chached flat file as an intermediate for the data. Set an expire time of 5 seconds or whatever is appropriate. Name the data file as the query key=value string. In the ajax request if the data file is older than your cooldown time, then refresh, if not, use the value stored in your data file.

Also, you might be underestimating the strength of the mysql query cache mechanism. If you're using mysql query cache, I doubt there would be any significant performance dip over doing it the way I just described. If the query was being query cached by mysql then virtually the only slowdown effect would be from the network layer between your application and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what role replication can play in your architecture. If you need to scale out, you might consider replicating your tables from InnoDB to MyISAM. The MyISAM engine automatically maintains a table count if you are doing `count(*)` queries. If you are doing `count(col) where` queries, then you need to rely heavily on well designed indicies. In that case you your count queries might take shape like so:

```
alter table A add index ixA (a, b);
select count(a) using from A use index(ixA) where a=1 and b=2;
```

Comment: if you have to force indexes on simple queries you are slowing things down, not speeding them up.

Comment: Johan, I've have to disagree. I've had to add multiple indexes to a table and add USE INDEX to the query to get around the default index selection. This is also a pertinent tactic if you have queries running against slaves with altered indexes, where you wouldn't be running the query against a write master node.

Answer (score 0):

I feel crazy for suggesting this as it seems that no-one else has, but have you considered client-side caching? JavaScript isn't terrible at dealing with large lists, especially if they're relatively simple lists.

I know that your ideal is that you have a desire to make the numbers completely accurate, but heuristics are your friend here, especially since synchronization will never be 100% -- a slow connection or high latency due to server-side traffic will make the AJAX request out of date, especially if that data is not a constant. ***IF THE DATA CAN BE EDITED BY OTHER USERS, SYNCHRONICITY IS IMPOSSIBLE USING AJAX. IF IT CANNOT BE EDITED BY ANYONE ELSE, THEN CLIENT-SIDE CACHING WILL WORK AND IS LIKELY YOUR BEST OPTION***. Oh, and if you're using some sort of port connection, then whatever is pushing to the server can simply update all of the other clients until a sync can be accomplished.

If you're willing to do that form of caching, you can also cache the results on the server too and simply refresh the query periodically.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you really need some sort of caching mechanism on the server side. Whether it's a MySQL table or memcache, either would work. But to reduce the number of calls to the server, retrieve the full list of cached counts in one request and cache that locally in javascript. That's a pretty simple way to eliminate almost 12M server hits.

You could probably even store the count information in a cookie which expires in an hour, so subsequent page loads don't need to query again. That's if you don't need real time numbers.

Many of the latest browser also support local storage, which doesn't get passed to the server with every request like cookies do.

You can fit a lot of data into a 1-2K json data structure. So even if you have thousands of possible count options, that is still smaller than your typical image. Just keep in mind maximum cookie sizes if you use cookie caching.