# Calculate all filter fields combinations

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, database

I have a client application that is allowing user to filter products (cellphones) by criteria - there are groups of checkboxes and user can select many of them to filter only products he likes.

[Checkboxes for filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMKnb.png)

I am using AJAX and every time the user changes something in the filter, a request is made to calculate current number of results that would be shown to the user if submitted current form, and this number appears to the user as 'current products count'. I am caching the retrieved values to speed it up in future search.

Now I would like to make a script that would precalculate all these values (in the background) and cache them. The problem is, there is a lot of combinations that the user can make.

Let's say I have these arrays (according to the filter image I provided). The values are present as checkboxes under corresponding cathegory:

```
var brand = ["Apple", "Honor", "Huawei", "Xiaomi", "Nokia", "Sony", "LG", "Motorola", "HTC", "Lenovo"];
var os = ["Android", "iOS", "Windows", "None"];
var memory = ["8", "16", "32", "64", "128", "516"];
```

Now I should think of a way to calculate all possible combination, with **0-N values of each array**.

e.g.

```
var generatedObject = {
    brand: ["Apple", "Honor", "Huawei"],
    os: [],
    memory: ["8", "16"]
}
```

Every cathegory can have 0 (like `os` in example), some or all values present.

I can only think of nested loops, which is not the perfect solution, as I would have to adjust the code every time a whole array would be added or removed. Is there maybe another, more flexible way?

Also, I would appreciate if anyone could post any links and articles related to filtering like this.
I only found this topic related to my problem: [Mysql count rows using filters on high traffic database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302985/mysql-count-rows-using-filters-on-high-traffic-database)

Comment: It's 240 combinations. This seems like a fairly small number to me. Here's an example I like of a combination filter in use on a small data set: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/GFbAs

Comment: It's 240 combinations if you always take 1 of each array. I also need to calculate combinations where I take 0 from 1st array, 2 from 1st array, ... to all from first array, and the same with all other arrays. See the `generatedObject` in my example, that's how one combination might look like.

Comment: Sure, but (I think) we're only concerned with one (and zero) at this stage. You can do a further search to return all entries for each combo.